# Have there been any patented physical models or computational algorithms?

Tags: soft-question, history, algorithms

There was a recent question (linked below) on the Law SE about the potential to patent algorithms. It appears there is a lot of gray area in the subject.

Of course natural laws cannot be subject to patent, but I couldn't help but wonder if some theoretical work in physics could qualify. Have there been any well-known approximate physical models or schemes that have been patented? (e.g. consider something like the Eikonal approximation for scattering... it doesn't quite reflect nature after all). What about computational schemes? (e.g. DFT)

Related:

- [If mathematical equations are not patentable, why are algorithms
  parentable?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/28236/)
- [Can an algorithm be patented?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/32482/)

Comment: Yeah, let's patent the laws of nature, why not? The human geenome is patented. Not a problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about ownership rather than actual physics.

Comment: @safesphere That's not what the question is about. Nor am I advocating such a thing.

Comment: @Qmechanic Could you explain why? I've recognized that Physics.SE is rather strict (rightfully and thankfully so, in many cases) in the scope of its questions. History and soft questions do not necessarily fall under the scope defined in the help center. Nevertheless such questions are asked; is my question not about the history of physics?

Comment: FWIW, history questions are [restricted](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8930/2451) on Phys.SE.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks for the reply. I often wish this SE had a broadened scope, as I enjoy the quality of its responses better than some other Q&A sites.